# Как сделать прокрутку камеры при проведение пальцем по экрану?

Tags: android, libgdx

как реализовать слайдер при проведении пальцем по экрану?

везде в примерах для прокрутки участвует клавиатура:

```
OrthographicCamera camera;
...
public void render () {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
        camera.position.x -= 5;
...
```

а как реализовать перемещение камеры при проведении пальцем по экрану?

Спасибо.

Comment: Используй GestureListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно написать класс, имплементировать GestureListener,  реализовать метод pan. Потом нужно создать GestureDetector, ему в конструктор передать твой GestureListener и установить его как InputProcessor. Тут глянь https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection
Кроме этого в метод  pan координаты прикосновения приходят в экранных координатах, через метод камеры unproject можно преобразовать в игровые.